# Can I build on a different tile to the one I terraform?

Tags: terra-mystica

In a game I played recently, there was an adjacent territory that was my home terrain that I wanted to build a dwelling on, but also the bonus for that round was terraforming, so I wanted to do a terraform on a separate tile as well.

Am I allowed to do that as Action #1?

On a related note - I take the two spades power action - can I use it to terraform two different tiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can only build on the space that you terraform. From [the rules](https://images.zmangames.com/filer_public/3c/b1/3cb1119d-85cb-4905-bfe6-d428a3024e1b/zm7240_terra_mystica_rules.pdf):

> First, you may change the type of one Terrain space. Then, if you have changed its type to your Home terrain, you may immediately build a Dwelling **on that space**.

If you are using the 2 free shovels power action, then you can use the second one to terraform a second adjacent space if the first one was enough to make your first space into your home terrain.

> (If these Spades do not suffice to transform a given Terrain space into your Home terrain, you may exchange Workers* for the missing Spade – at the current Exchange rate on your Exchange track. **If you only need one Spade to transform a Terrain space into your Home terrain, you may spend the second Spade on another Terrain space.** However, you may not place a Dwelling on this other space.)